# A rich:toolBarGroup with location="right", placed in a rich:toolbar is not visible when resolution is 1280x1024

Tags: richfaces

I have a rich:toolbar in which I have a rich:toolBarGroup located to right. The problem is that the rich:toolBarGroup located to right is not visible anymore when resolution is 1280x1024. Reading the official documentation and searching all over the internet, I didn't find an option to resize rich:toolbar depending on the resolution. And I think maybe this is not the only possible solution. 
Do you have any idea how the problem can be solved?

```
<rich:toolBar height="34" itemSeparator="line">
<rich:toolBarGroup id="#{toolbarGroupId}" location="right">
    <h:inputText style="font-size:10px;" id="quickSearch"
        onkeypress="return _quickSearchEntityListKeyPressed(event)"
        value="#{searchAction.textEntity}">
    </h:inputText>
    <a:commandButton id="quickSearchCmd" value="#{messages.search}"
        action="#{searchBean[searchMethod]}" eventsQueue="queue"
        reRender="entityListForm" image="img/_search18x18.gif"
        style="vertical-align: top"
        rendered="true">
    </a:commandButton>
</rich:toolBarGroup>
```

Comment: I thought of setting the width="1280px" to the rich:toolbar, in case the resolution is 1280x1024. But I must see how I will get information about the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the `location="right"` attribute be on the `rich:toolBarGroup` tag instead of the `rich:toolBar` ? I don't think a RichFaces toolbar has a size by the way, or something like 100% of its parent. So if it overflow your resolution, maybe the problem comes from the parent tag.

And just to say it, I think your code would be cleaner if the Javascript was outside the toobar.

Regards.

Comment: I am sorry. Indeed, rich:toolBarGroup is the one that has location="right". I edited my post and removed the trouble causing parts. So, the problem remains.